# NotImplementedException when decrypting RSA signed hash

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, uwp

I want to verify a **private key signed SHA256 hash** using the **CryptographicEngine** in a UWP application. The hash is created externally and is signed with a private RSA key with passphrase. For this example however, I also generate the unsigned hash. Both hashes are then compared at the end to verify that they are the same.

I have created my private and public keys using OSX command line, specified in [this blog](https://rietta.com/blog/2012/01/27/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/).

This gave me two `.pem` files. My public key has the following structure:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3fasaNKpXDf4B4ObQ76X
qOaSRaedFCAHvsW4G0PzxL/...ETC ETC
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Here is my C# code to decrypt the hash:

```
        //HASH THE INPUT STRING
        var inputText = "stringtohash";

        // put the string in a buffer, UTF-8 encoded...
        IBuffer input = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(inputText,
            BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        // hash it...
        var hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("SHA256");

        IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(input);

        // format it...
        string ourhash = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashed);

        Debug.WriteLine(ourhash);

        //CONVERT EXTERNAL HASH TO BUFFER
        IBuffer data = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String("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");

        //CONVERT PUBLIC KEY TO BUFFER
        IBuffer publickey = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3fasaNKpXDf4B4ObQ76XqOaSRaedFCAHvsW4G0PzxL / RuAQFz80esZPyyDCps1PAbTKzQ + QblChPo7PJkbsU4HzNN4PIRGh5xum6SRmdvOowrlTUtyxdOkRJoFxmiR / VCea + PUspt26F7PLcK9ao5 + hVzMvPuqdYenqzd01f1t5hQEhFQ9qjB6Es8fpizHd / RSRfZ7n6rVKm9wYfCRLB7GJ7IHhWGuZrx9fjzsbW8eagu06qRhnUuR5oDVjXC8ZeazsRiw50xMuOzkhX9Oo081IYikwCgseJmQhT7vF4lZoyeB4qJpwTCA + glSy1w9N8ZfxyXK8QaT2RsrBrzl0ZCwIDAQAB");

        // Open an asymmetric algorithm provider for the specified algorithm. 
        AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider rsa = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);

        // Import Key
        CryptographicKey key =  rsa.ImportPublicKey(publickey, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo);

        // Decrypt the Hash using our Key
        IBuffer result = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, data, null);

        Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());

        //Compare the two hashes

        if (data == result) {

            //Hash is verified!
        }
```

Unfortunately when reaching the `Decrypt` method I get a `NotImplementedException` with error

> The method or operation is not implemented

I researched online and I understand what needs to happen in theory but I don't know how to debug this further. What can I try?

Comment: The description is lacking. Is the SHA256 hash encrypted by a public key? If so why is it being decrypted with a public key ad not the private key. One generally does not encrypt with the private key unless signing.

Comment: Yes the SHA256 is signed with private key. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both called PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, the padding for signature generation and encryption ***is not identical***, see [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) for more details.

If you look at [the `RsaPkcs1` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetricalgorithmnames.rsapkcs1) you can see it is aimed at encryption:

> Use the string retrieved by this property to set the asymmetric algorithm name when you call the `OpenAlgorithm method`. The string represents an RSA public key algorithm that uses PKCS1 to pad the plaintext. No hash algorithm is used.

As I don't see any option for "raw RSA", i.e. RSA without padding, it seems you are only able to verify your signature. However, RSA decryption expects an RSA private key. It's very likely that you get the error because of this: if you try and decrypt with a public key it will fail.

If you want to precompute the hash you can use [`VerifySignatureWithHashInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.verifysignaturewithhashinput?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

For other functionality you may have to use e.g. the C# lightweight API of Bouncy Castle. In the end you don't need platform provided cryptography to verify a signature.

Comment: Thanks. I solved my issue by using the method VerifySignatureWithHashInput.